# CSS isn't able to generate dropdown menu link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a dropdown button in my main menu, but I don't knon what is going wrong. I tried many examples but none worked.
Can anyone please help me in making at least one link as a dropdown?

By the way I tried using  `.dropdown` as id and class, but it is still showing inline. I also tried some w3school examples.

### navbar css

```
.header-nav {
background-color: rgba(0, , 6, 0.3);
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
left: 0;
height: 80px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
width: 100%;
z-index: 999;
 }
 .header-nav.bg-color {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
    .header-nav.menu-bg {
    height: 56px;
 }

           /* menu */
         .navbar-brand {
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 36px;
                      font-weight: bold;
               line-height: 80px;
              padding: 0;
             text-transform: capitalize;
              }
           .header-nav.menu-bg  .navbar-brand {
                            line-height: 56px;
                         }
           .navbar-brand:hover {
                     color: #fff;
               }
                .navbar-brand > img {
                     height: 80px;
                   -webkit-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
                    -moz-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
                -o-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
                transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
               }
         .menu-bg .navbar-brand > img {
              height: 56px;
          }
       .bg-color .main-menu .navbar-nav li a {
               color: #000;
       }
         .main-menu .navbar-nav li a {
          color: #22a265;
          font-size: 16px;
          padding: 30px 20px;
         text-transform: uppercase;
       -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
           -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
         transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
           }
      .menu-bg .main-menu .navbar-nav li a {
            padding: 18px 15px;
           color: #222;
         }
     .menu-bg .main-menu .navbar-nav li a:hover {
           color: #fafafa;
           }
       .main-menu .navbar-nav li a:focus {
         background-color: transparent;
         }
      .main-menu .navbar-nav li a:hover, .main-menu .navbar-nav li a.active {
                color: #fff;
             background-color: #04b962;
         }
     .menu-bg {
           background-color: #fff;
         box-shadow: 0 2px 10px -1px rgba(87, 97, 100, 0.35);
         }
      a img.logo-color  {
           opacity: 0;
            height: 0;
          }
     .menu-bg a img.logo-white  {
         opacity: 0;
        height: 0;
           }
          .menu-bg a img.logo-color  {
                opacity: 1;
           }

           .main-menu .navbar-nav li a.menubgactive {
          background-color: #f0f0f0;
              }
           .main-menu .navbar-nav li a.menubgactive:hover {
           background-color: #04b962;
           }

      /* navbar-toggle responsive menu */
         .navbar-toggle {
            border: none;
        background: transparent;
         }
       .navbar-toggle.collapsed .icon-bar {
             background-color: #04b962;
       }
      .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
               background-color: #e91313;
        }
     .navbar-toggle:hover {
                background: transparent;
        }
         .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
                width: 32px;
                height: 4px;
           -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease 0s;
           -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease 0s;
           -ms-transition:all 0.2s ease 0s;
           -o-transition:all 0.2s ease 0s;
            transition:all 0.2s ease 0s;
          }
      .navbar-toggle .top-bar {
           -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
         -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
          -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
          -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
            transform:rotate(45deg);
            transform-origin: 10% 10%;
         }
          .navbar-toggle .middle-bar {
                opacity: 0;
         }
          .navbar-toggle .bottom-bar {
                -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
               -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
               -o-transform:rotate(-45deg);
               -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
              transform:rotate(-45deg);
                transform-origin: 10% 90%;
                     }
         .navbar-toggle.collapsed .top-bar {
                -moz-transform:rotate(0);
               -webkit-transform:rotate(0);
               -o-transform:rotate(0);
                -ms-transform:rotate(0);
                transform:rotate(0);
                 }
           .navbar-toggle.collapsed .middle-bar {
                        opacity: 1;
         }
            .navbar-toggle.collapsed .bottom-bar {
               -moz-transform:rotate(0);
               -webkit-transform:rotate(0);
                    -o-transform:rotate(0);
                -ms-transform:rotate(0);
                 transform:rotate(0);
                }


                 .dropdown {
                    position: relative;
                     display: inline-block;
                     }

               .dropdown-content {
                     display: none;
                      position: absolute;
                          background-color: #f1f1f1;
                     min-width: 160px;
                   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                   z-index: 1;
                   }

           .dropdown-content a {
                         color: black;
                         padding: 12px 16px;
                         text-decoration: none;
                         display: block;
                       }

              .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

             .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

             .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

### menu html:

```
      <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <nav class="main-menu">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                                <img class="logo logo-white" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
                                <img class="logo logo-color" src="images/logo-color.png" alt="logo">
                            </a>
                        </div><!--End navbar-header -->
                        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#pricingtable">Pricing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
                                <li><a class="last" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!--End navbar -->
                    </nav>
                </div><!--End col -->
            </div><!--End row -->
        </div><!--End container -->
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: no.. this menu is from a downloaded template

Comment: the classes you have used are of bootstrap like container, nav, navbar-nav  let me give you code snippet how to to do it correctly

Comment: yes the theme is using bootstrap.. i just checked..  i have a little idea of it though..

Comment: You haven't set up any dropdown menus in your HTML. Which menu item(s) should have dropdowns, and what are the links for those  pages?

Comment: @FluffyKitten yes i didnt.. i tried it on my system but thought it would be better to give a clean code here..  can you please do it for 'portfolio' link..thnkyou

Answer (score 0):

In your head section add this css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">de here
```

and then in your body add this navigation code of bootstrap you can customize it according to your need

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div><!--End col -->
</div><!--End row -->
```

and in footer add these script files without these dropdown will not work

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and after you have followed the above steps your menu and dropdown will look like below

[image]

Comment: hi anku.. this will change the whole menu.. i just want a single item to be a dropdown

Comment: checkout saad's answer.. that is exactly my menu look rytnow.. i do not want to change the entire menu just one link as dropdown button.. thankyou for your patience

Comment: well my purpose was to give you idea for the dropdown you can take the dropdown code from my code snippet and place it in your code, let me know if you face any problem

Comment: but still you need to follow the standard as i have mentioned to have your menu fully functional with dropdown because your code have been partially written in html, css and partially in bootstrap and this will not work

Comment: i tried using this and other menu from codepen.. .. as am not good with css.. i was ending up complexing my problem.. i wasted a whole day in it.. what you just told has already benn tried mate.. i appreciate your patience and generosity.. thnks :)

Answer (score 0):

in your code, you are using  `Bootstrap` classes that do not work without `Bootstrap` and drop down uses `jquery` also,  make sure to include them, I have used `CDN BOOTSTRAP` please check snippets

```css
.header-nav {
background-color: rgba(0, , 6, 0.3);
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
left: 0;
height: 80px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
width: 100%;
z-index: 999;
 }
 .header-nav.bg-color {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
    .header-nav.menu-bg {
    height: 56px;
 }

           /* menu */
         .navbar-brand {
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 36px;
                      font-weight: bold;
               line-height: 80px;
              padding: 0;
             text-transform: capitalize;
              }
           .header-nav.menu-bg  .navbar-brand {
                            line-height: 56px;
                         }
           .navbar-brand:hover {
                     color: #fff;
               }
                .navbar-brand > img {
                     height: 80px;
                   -webkit-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
                    -moz-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
                -o-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
                transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
               }
         .menu-bg .navbar-brand > img {
              height: 56px;
          }
       .bg-color .main-menu .navbar-nav li a {
               color: #000;
       }
         .main-menu .navbar-nav li a {
          color: #22a265;
          font-size: 16px;
          padding: 30px 20px;
         text-transform: uppercase;
       -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
           -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
         transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
           }
      .menu-bg .main-menu .navbar-nav li a {
            padding: 18px 15px;
           color: #222;
         }
     .menu-bg .main-menu .navbar-nav li a:hover {
           color: #fafafa;
           }
       .main-menu .navbar-nav li a:focus {
         background-color: transparent;
         }
      .main-menu .navbar-nav li a:hover, .main-menu .navbar-nav li a.active {
                color: #fff;
             background-color: #04b962;
         }
     .menu-bg {
           background-color: #fff;
         box-shadow: 0 2px 10px -1px rgba(87, 97, 100, 0.35);
         }
      a img.logo-color  {
           opacity: 0;
            height: 0;
          }
     .menu-bg a img.logo-white  {
         opacity: 0;
        height: 0;
           }
          .menu-bg a img.logo-color  {
                opacity: 1;
           }

           .main-menu .navbar-nav li a.menubgactive {
          background-color: #f0f0f0;
              }
           .main-menu .navbar-nav li a.menubgactive:hover {
           background-color: #04b962;
           }

      /* navbar-toggle responsive menu */
         .navbar-toggle {
            border: none;
        background: transparent;
         }
       .navbar-toggle.collapsed .icon-bar {
             background-color: #04b962;
       }
      .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
               background-color: #e91313;
        }
     .navbar-toggle:hover {
                background: transparent;
        }
         .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
                width: 32px;
                height: 4px;
           -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease 0s;
           -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease 0s;
           -ms-transition:all 0.2s ease 0s;
           -o-transition:all 0.2s ease 0s;
            transition:all 0.2s ease 0s;
          }
      .navbar-toggle .top-bar {
           -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
         -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
          -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
          -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
            transform:rotate(45deg);
            transform-origin: 10% 10%;
         }
          .navbar-toggle .middle-bar {
                opacity: 0;
         }
          .navbar-toggle .bottom-bar {
                -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
               -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
               -o-transform:rotate(-45deg);
               -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
              transform:rotate(-45deg);
                transform-origin: 10% 90%;
                     }
         .navbar-toggle.collapsed .top-bar {
                -moz-transform:rotate(0);
               -webkit-transform:rotate(0);
               -o-transform:rotate(0);
                -ms-transform:rotate(0);
                transform:rotate(0);
                 }
           .navbar-toggle.collapsed .middle-bar {
                        opacity: 1;
         }
            .navbar-toggle.collapsed .bottom-bar {
               -moz-transform:rotate(0);
               -webkit-transform:rotate(0);
                    -o-transform:rotate(0);
                -ms-transform:rotate(0);
                 transform:rotate(0);
                }


                 .dropdown {
                    position: relative;
                     display: inline-block;
                     }

               .dropdown-content {
                     display: none;
                      position: absolute;
                          background-color: #f1f1f1;
                     min-width: 160px;
                   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                   z-index: 1;
                   }

           .dropdown-content a {
                         color: black;
                         padding: 12px 16px;
                         text-decoration: none;
                         display: block;
                       }

              .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

             .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

             .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <nav class="main-menu">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                                <img class="logo logo-white" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
                                <img class="logo logo-color" src="images/logo-color.png" alt="logo">
                            </a>
                        </div><!--End navbar-header -->
                        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#pricingtable">Pricing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
                                <li><a class="last" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!--End navbar -->
                    </nav>
                </div><!--End col -->
            </div><!--End row -->
        </div><!--End container -->
```

Comment: hi saad.. i want only one link to be dropdown in my menu.. like about, or portfolio as dropdown button

Answer (score 0):

Use following format to add boootstrap 4:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css"></style>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    

</body>
</html>
```

I have just figured out you are using older version of Bootstrap. SO for Bootstrap 3, use following skeleton:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css"></style>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for a drop-down menu I recommend using Bootstrap's Drop-Down button group.
Here's an example.

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

There are more options here at Bootstrap.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/dropdowns/

P.S.
You need to add the bootstrap links and script in

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/

Both the CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: hi please check @saad abbasi's answer.. my menu is looking exactly same.. i just want a single link to be adropdown ..

Comment: Yeah so if you use bootstrap's drop down button it will work

Comment: the thing is there is no HTML drop down by default you need to make it with js. So what bootstrap does is make things easier.

Comment: ohh you want only one item well that's simple. Just remove the rest.

Comment: hi nathan.. bootstrap dropdown button is working but it is not properly aligning with my menu...

Comment: you mean aligned vertically. ohhh try to make a few adjustments with margin-top or the margin-bottom to align it to the way you want.

Comment: P.S. if I have helped you would you mind giving my answer a tick saying that its helpful.
Thank You,
Nathan